# How to prevent Goo.gl opens links via API?

Tags: php, api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I'm using goo.gl service to shorten registered users activation link. Once the user clicks that link he gets activated. But I noticed that all new registered users are automatically activated just after shortening the activation link. I've stopped the shortening service and send the long URL and it works fine without getting activated which means URLs send to goo.gl get opened. So is there any way to prevent goo.gl from opening links while shortening via API? If not so what's the service which i can count on instead of google?

```
    $apiKey = 'KEY';
    $postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl);
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    $curlObj = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    $response = curl_exec($curlObj);
    $json = json_decode($response);
    curl_close($curlObj);
    if (strlen(trim($json->id)) > 0) {
        return $json->id;
    } else {
        return $longUrl;
    }
```

Comment: You can't disable it as google crawls the page for a title. Best bet is to include a button that will activate the user when pressed

Comment: I'm wondering though, whats wrong with just sending the long url to the user?

Comment: because it's sent via sms and we need it to be short – Olle Kelderman

Comment: Ah, that makes a ton of sense :)